# Cardinality bound of a sigma algebra without transfinite induction or (full) axiom of choice.

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

### The Question

Let $A$ be a set. It is true that there exists some cardinality $\kappa_A$ such that whenever $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and $\Sigma$ contains a generating set of cardinality $|A|$, then $|\Sigma| \leq \kappa_A$. The proofs I know all either involve transfinite induction up to $\omega_1$, or the full axiom of choice. Is there a way to prove this fact that doesn't use transfinite induction, and doesn't use the full axiom of choice (but may use the axiom of countable choice, or the axiom of dependent choice)? The cardinality $\kappa_A$ need not be optimal.

### Background

I'm trying to construct the free *abstract* $\sigma$-algebra (i.e. not subsets of a set) generated by a set $A$ using simple tools, and in particular, without the full axiom of choice. To do this, it suffices to bound the size of any $\sigma$-algebra generated by $A$. However, I'm having trouble coming up with a simple explanation for why such a $\sigma$-algebra is bounded.

I've seen a proof that uses transfinite induction up to $\omega_1$ to effectively list out all elements of $\Sigma$, when $A$ generates $\Sigma$. This gives the bound $\kappa_A \leq \max(2^{\aleph_0}, |A|)$. While this doesn't use the full axiom of choice, I don't think it is simple to explain to someone who isn't already aware that $\omega_1$ can be well-ordered without the axiom of choice, or who isn't already familiar with transfinite induction. So I am looking for an alternative proof, if such a proof exists.

Comment: Can you explain $\sigma$-algebras to someone who doesn't understand unions, complements, or countability?

Comment: Is $A$ *actually* a concrete set, or is it just a cardinality of a generating set? This can result is *wildly* different answers.

Comment: $A$ is an actual concrete set, although I don't know why it makes a difference. And yes, I get that $\sigma$-algebras are not inherently simple objects, but there's a big step from countable sets to transfinite induction. To make this question concrete, I'm only asking for a proof that doesn't use transfinite induction (or the full axiom of choice).

Comment: Sorry, I may have misread your question. There only needs to be a generating subset of $\Sigma$ of cardinality $|A|$. I've edited the question to make this clearer.

Comment: If there is some (well-ordered) cardinal $\kappa$ of uncountable cofinality, there is an obvious upper bound along $\vert \mathcal{P}^{\kappa}(\vert A \vert) \vert$. Otherwise, good question. I would imagine the answer could be no.

Comment: In any case, I think you are mislead by thinking that being able to well-order $\Sigma$ or $A$ is related to having some upper bound. The only use of choice in these upper bound proofs is that you are finished generating all of $\Sigma$ after $\omega_1$ many steps (which might be false otherwise). Also, $\omega_1$ is always well-ordered, by definition.